# SpaCy Parenthesis tokenization: pairs of (LRB, RRB) not tokenized correctly

Tags: python, spacy

When `RRB` is not separated by a space with its following word, it will be recognized as part of the word.

```
In [34]: nlp("Indonesia (CNN)AirAsia ")                                                               
Out[34]: Indonesia (CNN)AirAsia 

In [35]: d=nlp("Indonesia (CNN)AirAsia ")                                                             

In [36]: [(t.text, t.lemma_, t.pos_, t.tag_) for t in d]                                              
Out[36]: 
[('Indonesia', 'Indonesia', 'PROPN', 'NNP'),
 ('(', '(', 'PUNCT', '-LRB-'),
 ('CNN)AirAsia', 'CNN)AirAsia', 'PROPN', 'NNP')]

In [39]: d=nlp("(CNN)Police")                                                                         

In [40]: [(t.text, t.lemma_, t.pos_, t.tag_) for t in d]                                              
Out[40]: [('(', '(', 'PUNCT', '-LRB-'), ('CNN)Police', 'cnn)police', 'VERB', 'VB')]
```

Expected result is

```
In [37]: d=nlp("(CNN) Police")                                                                        

In [38]: [(t.text, t.lemma_, t.pos_, t.tag_) for t in d]                                              
Out[38]: 
[('(', '(', 'PUNCT', '-LRB-'),
 ('CNN', 'CNN', 'PROPN', 'NNP'),
 (')', ')', 'PUNCT', '-RRB-'),
 ('Police', 'Police', 'NOUN', 'NNS')]
```

Is this a bug? 
Any suggestions to fix the issue?

Comment: As a workaround, you might pre-process the corpus beforehand with a regex like `re.sub(r'\b\)\b', r'\g<0> ', txt)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good to know this! Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you think this is a bug which needs us to fire an issue?

Comment: I am not sure it is a bug, since you can always extend the basic functionality, probably there was some reason behind not adding this rule to infixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom tokenizer to add the `r'\b\)\b'` rule (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zc09br/2)) to `infixes`. The regex matches a `)` that is preceded with any word char (letter, digit, `_`, and in Python 3, some other rare characters) and is followed with this type of char.

You may customize this regex further, so a lot depends on what context you want to match the `)` in.

See the full Python demo:

```
import spacy
import re
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    infixes = tuple([r"\b\)\b"]) +  nlp.Defaults.infixes
    infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
    prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
    suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=nlp.tokenizer.token_match,
                                rules=nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp("Indonesia (CNN)AirAsia ")

print([(t.text, t.lemma_, t.pos_, t.tag_) for t in doc] )
```

Output:

```
[('Indonesia', 'Indonesia', 'PROPN', 'NNP'), ('(', '(', 'PUNCT', '-LRB-'), ('CNN', 'CNN', 'PROPN', 'NNP'), (')', ')', 'PUNCT', '-RRB-'), ('AirAsia', 'AirAsia', 'PROPN', 'NNP')]
```

Comment: actually the model you start with in your example was not trained on text tokenized by the custom tokenizer thereby attaching the custom tokenizer after it was trained will affect its performance most likely negatively

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution that does not need custom tokenizer

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')

infixes = (
    LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_ICONS
    + [
        r"(?<=[0-9])[+\-\*^](?=[0-9-])",
        r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\.(?=[{au}{q}])".format(
            al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
        ),
        r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
        r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),

        # Additions to infix rules begin here

        # bracket between characters
        r"\b\)\b"

    ]
)

infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer
```

Then save this model and use it as a base model when training your new model.

Comment: Full example: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions